# Java ArrayList StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, arraylist, stack-overflow

This is my first time asking a question so please be patient. I am working on a school assignment and have been battling a stackoverflow error that I do not know enough about to get to the bottom of. The errors are indicated by ~~~:

The sections of code from the stack trace are as follows:

```
public class Employee extends StaffMember {
    public static final int DEFAULT_SIN = 123456789;
    public static final double MINIMUM_WAGE = 400.00;
    protected int socialInsuranceNumber = DEFAULT_SIN;;
    protected double payRate = MINIMUM_WAGE;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     * @param streetAddress
     * @param phone
     * @param socialInsuranceNumber
     * @param payRate
     */
    public Employee(String name, String address, String phone, int socialInsuranceNumber, double payRate) {
    ~~~ super(name, address, phone);
        this.socialInsuranceNumber = socialInsuranceNumber;
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }
public abstract class StaffMember extends Staff {
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Default Name";
    public static final String DEFAULT_ADDRESS = "Default Address";
    public static final String DEFAULT_PHONE = "Default Phone";

    protected String name;
    protected String address;
    protected String phone;

    /**
     * default constructor
     */
    public StaffMember() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param address
     * @param phone
     *            abstract class can not be instantiated therefore should not
     *            have constructors
     */

    ~~~ public StaffMember(String name, String address, String phone) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
public class Staff {

    public ArrayList<StaffMember> staffList;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of type Staff.
     */
    public Staff() {

        staffList = new ArrayList<StaffMember>(6);

    ~~~ staffList.add(new Executive("Hilary", "203 Whitewater Line", "871-0469", 123456789, 5000, 0));
        staffList.add(new Employee("Thomas", "1000 Robson Street", "604-0000", 010203040, 1500));
        staffList.add(new Hourly("Condoleeza", "678 Fifth Ave.", "905-0690", 958473625, 18.50, 0));
        staffList.add(new Volunteer("Kimberly", "1200 West Point Grey Road", "514-8374"));
        staffList.add(new Volunteer("Jean", "321 Shawinigate Lane", "613-7282"));

    }
public class Executive extends Employee {

    private double bonus;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public Executive() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     * @param address
     * @param phone
     * @param socialInsuranceNumber
     * @param payRate
     */
    public Executive(String name, String address, String phone, int socialInsuranceNumber, double payRate, double bonus) {
        super(name, address, phone, socialInsuranceNumber, payRate);
        this.awardBonus(bonus);
    }
```

Comment: Please add error log.

Comment: You didn't paste all the code. I can't see awardBonus method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Circular chain of constructor invocations. 
Your base class constructor `Staff()` is instantiating child classes which in turn invoke self constructor leading to infinite chain causing `stackOverFlow` error.

Also, it doesn't seem correct for `StaffMember` to extend `Staff` . As staff is the entire staff consisting of all the employees and `StaffMember` represents a single employee. There is no `is A`  relationship between the two.

You should remove the `extends Staff` from StaffMember and the code should also work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a circular instantiation of objects which is causing your stack to overflow.

In your `Staff` constructor you are instantiating many classes, such as `Executive` and `Employee`. Your `Executive` class `extends` the `Employee` class and your `Employee` class `extends` your `StaffMember` class.

When you do that, the constructor of `Staff` will be called again *implicitly* (by calling `super()` from `Executive`, then `Employee` and then `StaffMember`) and repeat the entire process, thus consuming all your memory.
Getting rid of your class that `extends Staff` would probably solve your problem (probably the problematic one is the `extends` from `StaffMember` which is the last on the chain of invocations).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your class A calls the constructor of class B. The constructor of class B calls the constructor of class A. You have an infinite recursion call, that's why you end up having a `StackOverflowError`. You are going into an circular call of constructors.

Java supports having circular dependencies between classes, the problem here is only related to constructors calling each others.